# Pegar string antes com regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou precisando fazer uma regex pra uma aplicação do qual preciso remover uma determinada combinação de carácteres de dentro de uma string. Explicando melhor o problema.

Eu tenho uma string que retorna do banco de dados, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
EVENTDATE:10/10/2015|*EDITAR_EVENTDATE:IwCalendar|EVENTTIME_INI:12:00|EVENTTIME_END:13:00|RANKINGHC:0|ALERGIAS:0|QUAIS_ALERGIAS:|INFECCAO:0|DATA_INFEC:|SITIO:0|QUADROCLINICO:|ASPECTO:0| ...
```

Nessa string eu tenho valores como esse:

```
*EDITAR_EVENTDATE:IwCalendar|
*EDITAR_TQT_DTULTTROCA:IwCalendar|
*EDITAR_GTT_DTULTTROCA:IwCalendar|
```

É um padrão, eu preciso remover tudo o que começa com `*` e tenha o valor `IwCalendar` e o pipe `|` no final da string, ou seja, remover os ditos cujos.

Preciso fazer algo genérico pois existem dezenas de campos como esse.

Desde já agradeço pela força!!!
Bom dia à todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ewerton,

Você pode fazer assim.

```
var stringTeste = "EVENTDATE:10/10/2015|*EDITAR_EVENTDATE:IwCalendar|EVENTTIME_INI:12:00|EVENTTIME_END:13:00|RANKINGHC:0|ALERGIAS:0|QUAIS_ALERGIAS:|INFECCAO:0|DATA_INFEC:|SITIO:0|QUADROCLINICO:|ASPECTO:0|*EDITAR_EVENTDATEEND:IwCalendar|";


var expressaoRegular = /\*.*?IwCalendar\|/gm;
var resultado = stringTeste.match(expressaoRegular);
console.log(resultado);

var resultado2 = stringTeste.replace(expressaoRegular, " ");

console.log(resultado2);
```

Aqui um exemplo no jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1b7s1yv8/1/